# Integration of kaa server and kaa sdk

Tags: kaa

I made c SDK and i copied the SDK in libs folder when i am running the build.sh  then it searching for demo_client(./demo_client:no such file or directory) and searching the .sh file in build directory only.

Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

check the permission on demo_client, make sure the permission to execute it is set.
use this if that's the case:

```
sudo chmod +x demo_client
```

hope this helps.

Comment: there is no such file(demo_client) exists. can you tell me where this file exists??

Comment: by default it should be in the build directory, if not, check where you run the build/cmake command

Answer (score 0):

Please check the correct version of documentation for the demo application you are trying to build. It seems like you either does this from incorrect location (directory) or uses obsolete build steps.